# Remote ID limit is 128 characters

Tags: auth-provider, open-id-connect

I have implemented an auth provider using OpenId Connect. But when I am trying to test the connection, I am getting this error - We can’t log you in because of the following error.
Remote_Id_Length: Remote ID limit is 128 characters. Any workaround on this?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the length of the identifier field can be increased. I'd recommend upvoting [this Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Ge1dcUAB/increase-the-length-of-the-identifier-field-to-match-the-openid-specs) on IdeaExchange platform so that Salesforce Product team can prioritize it.

This being a platform limitation, the Salesforce Product team has filed an investigation #W-10051485 internally to move up to 255 characters as the maximum length and there is no ETA yet.